# Free DNS service

Tags: server, dns

Edit: The answer selected was for something entirely different that what what I originally asked.

I tried to ask [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/295117/158495) but I suppose I wasn't clear enough.

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a domain, registered with a company that does not provide DNS. I need a nameserver so that my domain works. With the registrar I have inputed ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com.

I want to run my own nameserver. Both ns1 and ns2 should point to the same computer despite the fact that this defeats the purpose of redundancy.

With no success, I have tried several guides, including ones from the Ubuntu documentation. I have probably messed up the configuration pretty good by now.

Does anyone have a guide that they know works? How will I know it is working? Some guides prescribed reverse DNS, some did not, is it needed? What should I look for in a good guide?

Comment: unaccept the answer it it's not what you are looking for.

Comment: the other question you've asked is a duplicate that answers this question. Don't ask the same question trwice.

Comment: I have updated the question title to reflect the accepted answer for future visitors.

I asked another question because askubuntu.com suggested that I should "...please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question." I chose the second option.

To the admins, if all this is too messy, feel free to delete, the only reason I haven't is out of respect to the person who made an attempt at answering with the cloudflare suggestion. I didn't know they had a free NS service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the given below steps

**1.** Go to https://www.cloudflare.com/ & make an account

**2**. Add your website and it will guide you step by step

[image]

**3**.At last it will provide you with DNS settings and that is **ERIC.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM, 
MARY.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM**

**4**.Add there DNS settings to your domain & wait for at least 24 hours

**5**.After that you need to modify your DNS according to your **VPS IP** address at https://www.cloudflare.com/

[image]

So now You Domain is pointing to your **VPS**.

I would suggest you that you should install install [Zpanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/) on your VPS, so that you can manage your domain DNS & website easily.

Comment: ugh, that's not bind9, but is an interesting solution. I eneded up being able to resolve my question with https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html no reverse lookup

Comment: @dnsClueless - if yo want a good guide to BIND9, search for the book 'DNS and BIND' on Amazon or local bookstores. It's a good guide for setting up and running DNS servers.

Comment: I have very good Web Hosting experience. so its the only solution for you ...